# Objeto usando objeto

Tags: javascript, objetos

Criei objetos personagens que lançarão dados para validar suas ações. É possível o objeto `mago`, por exemplo, usar a função `dado.sorteio()`?

```
mago = {
  nome: "Misha",
  vida:50,
  ataque:7,
  esquiva:6,
  defesa: 4,
  esp : "Magia",
  especial : function(){
    
     return this.ataque*3;
    }
}

var ladra = {
  nome: "Aysha",
  vida : 60,
  ataque: 10,
  esquiva: 8,
  defesa: 6,
  esp : "facada",
  especial: function(){
    
    
    return this.ataque*2;
  }
}
  
  var guerreiro = {
    nome:"Thron",
    vida: 70,
    ataque: 10,
    esquiva: 7,
    defesa: 7,
    esp : "espadada",
    especial: function(){
      
      return this.ataque*1.5;
    }
  }
  
  var vilao = {
    nome : "Eskeleton",
    vida :30,
    ataque :22,
    esquiva :4,
    defesa :3
    }
var dado ={
     
    sorteio : function(){
      result = ""
      prompt("A sorte está lançada!\nClique 'Ok' para jogar o dado.");
      
       num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20+1);
    
    if(num >= 1 && num <= 5){
      
       result = "crítico";
       
       }else if(num > 5 && num <= 15){
         
       result = "acerto";
       
       }else{
         
        result = "perfeito";
      }
      
       prompt("O d20 deu "+num+"\nA ação foi "+result+"\n Clique 'Ok' para continuar");
      return this.result;
    } 
  }
```

Comment: O que você entende por "o objeto mago usar a função sorteio"?

Comment: sim pode, é outro objeto acessível dentro de mago